# LIRC irsend command change config file

Tags: raspbian, lirc

By default irsend take the default lircd configuration file. But irrecord save the recorded remote on a specific file :(

What I want to achieve is from a web interface launch the remote recording and once done be able to play a remote command with irsend  by specifying the file where it was saved.

I'll have multiple remotes and don't want to take the irrecord file and merge it into the default lirc config.

On the doc http://www.lirc.org/html/irsend.html they say nothing about changing the file used.

Answer (score 0):

The LIRC `irsend` docs are worse than useless, unfortunately.

I had some luck following the instructions [here](https://github.com/josemotta/IoT.Starter.Api/tree/master/gpio-base)

I think for your application, you will want to pay special attention to the placement of the file generated by `irrecord`. From what you're asking, I think if, once `irrecord` is completed, you copy the resultant `.conf` file over to `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/` and then restart the `lircd` service, you should be all set.